# C# needs help to understand

Tags: c#

Hi im doing a test program that uses a wrapper dll to communicate .net projects on a c++ dll. I wanted to create a Form Based example but the documentation only shows samples in console. There is a particular part that bothers me the most.

```
var mgr = new Pump("localhost",1,"test");
var result = mgr.Connect();
mgr.OnStart = sender => { var sga = sender.GetAllInfo(); };
```

what does sender means and is there anyway to rewrite it?

Thanks...

Comment: `sender` is the first (and only) parameter of an anonymous (lambda) function that attaches to the event (or possibly delegate) `OnStart`. Usually event handlers consist of the a `object sender` (In this case it could be the `Pump`) and EventArgs (or not, as in this case)

Comment: You could rewrite the lambda function as a real method taking sender as it's only parameter & assign that to OnStart. Check the definition of OnStart to find what type sender should be.

Comment: Next time, if you get error messages, please add them to the question directly instead of having people guess what the real problem could be.

Answer (score 5):

What you see here is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). In short terms the last line means something like:

> Assign to `mgr.OnStart` a handler that takes one parameter `sender` and executes the given code. The code invokes the `GetAllInfo()` method on the `sender` object and assigns the result to the `sga` variable.

What don't you like about it and why do you want to rewrite it?

---

Based on your comment I assume that the code in your question is actually itself invoked inside an event handler (for example a button's `OnClick` evnet handler) that already takes a parameter named `sender`.

In that case, simply rename the parameter name in either location, for example like this:

```
mgr.OnStart = sndr => { var sga = sndr.GetAllInfo(); };
```

Comment: For completeness sake, [here's the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to the lambda expression docs :-)

Comment: whenever i use that code it returns an error "A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter" in which i have no idea what it is.

Comment: @raven Edited my answer.

Comment: @Raven Then rename it. Let me guess: you put this code inside a Button_Click or something similar? A function that already uses an `object sender`?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers I thought it would be worthwhile showing the comparison of lambdas to normal methods...

### Example 1 - Method with single parameter and no return value

#### Lambda

```
...
mgr.OnStart = sender => { var sga = sender.GetAllInfo(); };
...
```

#### Normal method

```
...
mgr.OnStart = this.Mgr_Start;
...

private void Mgr_Start(object sender)
{
    var sga = sender.GetAllInfo();
}
```

Note that the parameter type of the above method is `object`. This will need to change depending on the signature of `OnStart`'s delegate.

### Example 2 - Method with no parameters, with a return value

#### Lambda

```
...
var getDateTime = () => DateTime.Now;

var dateTime = getDateTime();
...
```

#### Normal method

```
...
var dateTime = this.GetDateTime();
...

private DateTime GetDateTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now;
}
```